# Can I combine maghrib and isha, given that I have class during maghrib time?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, fiqh, school

I am a college student.

I have to take a class during maghrib time and there's no possible way to do it before or after. Would it be okay to combine it with Isha?

Comment: I don't have sources handy so I will comment.  I have been brought up believing and practicing by my parents.  The way I know it is if you know you are going to miss a salat's time beforehand, then combine it with the one that comes before.  In your case since the time window for Maghrib is very short, I would combine it with your Asr salat.  This is called Jam. This is better than 'missing' the Maghrib (kaza) and making kaza Maghrib at Isha time.  Also, ask your imam if such class time would somehow be interpreted under travelling rules.

Comment: Just sneak out of class for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Albeit my answer is from Shia Islam perspective, but it implies Sunni viewpoint to some extent, too, which on the whole can help you (God willing).

The cause that the Shia Muslims perform their Salahs (prayers) in 3 times is related to the Qur'anic verses and hadiths (traditions) on the issue. Albeit the Quran has pointed out that Salah (prayer) is wajib (obligatory) several times and actually it hasn’t gone into the details, this has mentioned of its times:

> “Maintain the prayer from the sun's decline till the darkness of the
> night, and [observe particularly] the dawn recital. Indeed the dawn
> recital is attended [by the angels of day and night]”.
> [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/514)

As well as this, pay heed that:

> As for the hadiths, there are hadiths that disclose that the prophet
> (pbuh) would [sometimes] pray the dhuhr and asr prayers together in
> one time, as was the case with the maghrib and isha prayers. He was
> asked about this matter, and he replied: “I did so in order that my
> nation may be free from hardship.”
>
> Imam Sadiq (as) says: “When the sun reaches the highest point in the
> sky and begins its decline (zawal/midday), it is the time for the
> dhuhr and asr prayers, the only thing is that the dhuhr prayer must be
> performed before asr. From then on, you have time to pray the prayers
> until sunset. There are also similar hadiths in Sunni sources that
> confirm this issue.

To see the complete text, which can be helpful/informative for you, kindly refer to the source below:

[www.islamquest.net/en](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2334)